# Pythagorean quadruple sum and product

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been working for a while on a problem that may be amenable to the methods
of Diophantus, but need help or a hint on how to proceed.  The problem statement
is:

Find all (possibly non-primitive) Pythagorean quadruples such that 9 times the
square of the sum of its four elements is equal to twice the product of its
three smallest elements.  Stated algebraically, find all natural numbers x,y,z
satisfying

$$2xyz = 9(x + y + z + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2})^2$$

The solution with the smallest product xyz is (84,108,126,186).  The largest
solution I've identified so far is (120,1120,6048,6152), but I cannot prove that
it is the last one.  Assuming that x,y,z are ranked smallest to largest, I have
been able to establish that 18z < xy < 225z/2, but unfortunately that doesn't
limit the possible values of z.  It can also be shown that 72 divides the
product xyz, but I'm at a loss to see if that contributes to finding all
solutions.

As a side note (or secondary problem), if the elements of a solution quadruple
are divided by their greatest common divisor, creating a primitive quadruple,
the largest element always seems to be prime.  I'm not sure if this result is
also something that can be proven, or if it helps in solving the main problem
above.

Comment: Have you tried applying Catalan’s complete solution (“parameterization”) to see if it gives you any insight?

Comment: No, I haven't, can you provide a web reference?

Comment: I saw your post on 9/24 -- yes, I have considered that parameterization as it is the one given (without attribution) in the Wiki article on Pythagorean quadruples.